# bash script regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash

I am not very familiar with Linux scripts using reg expressions,

but I need a script that will do this:

```
copy A/first_image.jpg  to B/first_image/thumb.jpg

copy A/second_image.jpg to B/second_image/thumb.jpg
```

etc.

every image in a folder A is copied in a directory with his name (in a directory B), and renamed to `thumb.jpg`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this script from parent directory of `A, B, C` etc:

```
for s in */*.jpg; do
    f="${s##*/}"
    d="${s%%/*}/${f%%.*}"
    mkdir -p "$d" 2>/dev/null
    cp "$s" "$d/thumb.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Read this manual for all details: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 1):

You use filename "globbing", which is comparable to, but different from, regular expressions as such. You also use a loop and the command `basename`. Like this:

```
for file in A/*.jpg
do
    base=`basename $file .jpg`
    mkdir -p B/${base}
    cp A/${base}.jpg B/${base}/thumb.jpg
done
```

Comment: I think you will also have to use the mkdir command before the copy

Comment: Well, I did write "like this", ha ha. I have fixed my answer to be more "exactly this".